# Configure VSTS to properly abort in case of errors

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Given the following `.vsts-ci.yml` file

```
queue: Hosted Linux Preview

steps:
- script: |
    false
    true
```

The expected behavior and the actual behavior differ.

Expected behavior: Build fails at the `false` command, `true` will not be executed.

Actual behavior: Build succeeds, `true` is executed after the `false` command.

Details:

I would expect the VSTS build to fail on the first command `false`.
However, VSTS executes the second command `true` as well and reports success.
This means that the shell is setup incorrectly for build systems. The correct setup would be to have `pipefail` and `errexit` set. But it seems that `errexit` is not set, and probably `pipefail` isn't set either.

Is there a way to get the correct behavior, that is, `pipefail` and `errexit`, within the YAML file, without using `bash -c` in the scripts section? I know I can easily workaround by just moving the command sequence into a shell script or `Makefile`, I just want to know if there is a configuration possibility to get the YAML file execute shell commands in a shell with `errexit` and `pipefail` set, preferably a `bash` shell.

Comment: I think it depends on how the agent translates the fragment on the machine, https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent If it generates a shell script with both lines, and only monitors the exit code of the whole script, then what you observed is by design.

Comment: @LexLi First of call, cool, thank you for pointing me to the source code. Maybe I can find the answer myself there. Second, if it's by design, it's bad design ignoring decades of lessons from build scripts, but I wouldn't be surprised by that level of ignorance from Microsoft.

Comment: The word “ignorance” might be over-weighted. Microsoft is still learning macOS and Linux, while VSTS has been Windows focused in its early ages. For me a design to monitor only the last exit code makes sense and is widely accepted on Windows. I am not familiar with Linux though, so could not comment further. You might create an issue on the GitHub to ping the developers directly, quicker than scanning the code on your own. They can help explain further what's the exact behavior and design intentions. You can show them how Linux common practices are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the bash shell created by VSTS does not have the `pipefail` and `errexit` flags set. See the following issue on GitHub about this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1803

But they can be set within the YAML file, like this:

```
queue: Hosted Linux Preview

steps:
- script: |
    set -e ; set -o pipefail
    false
    true
```